# ng-class doesn't always work with dynamic content until page is refreshed

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a directive that uses a template that is nested in an ng-repeat.  I am using different themes for the items on this directive (just different class names) that can be changed by the user when they change the theme of the overall site.  This functionality sometimes doesn't work when the user makes a theme change...unless they've refreshed the page at some point in which case it ALWAYS works when they make a theme change.  This is such strange behavior that I'm not really even sure where to start troubleshooting.  Here is the div where the class is set inside my directive template:

```
<div class="my-item" ng-class="[ma.getTheme(), ma.getSize()]">
...
</div>
```

here is the getTheme() function on the directive JS file:

```
function getTheme() {
            console.log('theme'+ma.item.themeId);
            return "theme" + ma.item.themeId;
        }
```

and here is the function on the controller JS file to change the theme:

```
function changeTemplate(selectedTemplate) {
...
for (var i = 0; i < ma.myItems.length; i++) {

                var item= ma.myItems[i];
                item.themeId = classes[index];

                var nextIndex = index + 1;
                if (nextIndex === classes.length) {
                    index = 0;
                } else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
}
```

where classes is just an array of different class numbers that get appended to the theme class name from the getTheme() function.

As I said above, this only fails when the page is first loaded (and not even always then).  When the page is refreshed, it always works.

What would change with a page refresh that would cause this to work?

TIA

Comment: Are you loading anything asynchronously that this depends on? It could be that when you first load the page it hits a server, and the class tries to resolve before the request returns, but then when you refresh the page it just uses a cached version, so the request resolves before the class function is run.

Comment: I am using ajax to load all of the items in the ma.myItems[] array (which includes the default themeId).  This is definitely already populated though before the user makes a theme change.  As a user, I could load the page and wait 20 minutes then try a theme change and it won't update the item's classes.  If however, I refresh then make a thousand changes, it will update the theme (class) everytime.  You may be on to something with a cached version of something, but it's not the data in the items array.

Comment: But do you maybe assign something on page load before the ajax request is complete, accidentally setting something to undefined? More code would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you're working with the same `ma` array the whole time, which you probably initially assign and then never change again? So, theoretically, this could be improperly assigned due to ajax timing, yes?

Comment: Nothing is set to undefined.  When I log out the themeId in the getTheme() function, on page load, it shows the default values from the server (which is correct), on theme change (without a refresh), it shows those same values (which is incorrect as they're being modified in the for loop on the changeTemplate() function in the controller), on theme change (after a refresh), they're showing the new values correctly.  I can add more code, just not sure what you'd want to see....

Comment: There's just a lot of potential problems that I can't solve with this limited of a code sample, for example, why doesn't your controller reference `ma` as `$scope.ma`? If it's accessible in the template, it must be on the scope. Maybe you address this in the rest of your code, maybe it's an error, there's no way for me to know. A full template and controller would be helpful.

Comment: ma is just the controller object (using controllerAs so I don't have to use $scope) https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/  unfortunately, my power went out from a big storm here so I can't access the code which is on my virtual machine at the moment.  I'll update my post later with more code for you when I can.

Comment: it turns out the array wasn't being updated on the parent scope.  I did a $rootScope.$broadcast() and that resolved it.  You were close with 3rd comment so if you want to make an answer out of that, I'll accept it as that is what got me moving in this direction.  I still dont' understand why it would all work after a refresh though....

Comment: Again, my guess is that the ajax request was cached and returned fast enough that it was set correctly on the initial assignment. But that's without seeing the whole structure of your code, so I may be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the look of a race condition to me. Like you're assigning content to something being returned by an ajax request, and sometimes the request completes in time, other times it doesn't. I would expect it works on refresh more reliably because the ajax request has been cached, and therefor resolves faster.